# iOS, Push, didReceiveRemoteNotification, impact of UIBackgroundFetchResult

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, completionhandler

I understand what "UIBackgroundFetchResult" means. But what is the impact?

Does something behave different when setting the completionHandler to "UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData" than "UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData"?
Is that relevant for Apples Push service?

Does Apple deliver more ofter/faster??

Or can I use the "variable" when the application wakes up? If yes, how?

Thanks
Stan

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBackgroundRefreshStatus

Answer (score 2):

I think the result to the completion handler helps iOS learn how often and at what times of the day new content usually shows up for your app. This helps it determine a heuristic on when it's good to wake your app up to get it some background time.

> Executing this block tells the system that it can move your app back to the suspended state and evaluate its power usage. Apps that download small amounts of content quickly and accurately reflect when they had content to download are more likely to receive execution time in the future than apps that take longer to download their content.

<del>Source: (search for "Fetching Small Amounts of Content Regularly" on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)).</del>

New Source: Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56)

Comment: Spot On! Great Answer.

Comment: The link is now dead, and did a search within the Apple site, and found a reference to it there as well, but that link was dead as well.

Comment: @drew.. I've added an updated source. Looks like they moved the page that contained that blurb.